# Django - Creating & Store PDF Files using XHTML2PDF

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

As of now we are using XHTML2PDF to dynamically generate PDFs and outputting to browser whenever required. Now our requirements is changed to generate the PDF only once and store it in the server. The link should be displayed to user to view the PDF. Could you please point out any resources or snippets to achieve this?

Comment: What does this have to do with django?

Comment: @Dolph The webapp is Django based and it uses XHTML2PDF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do. Observe:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

# get_pdf_contents should return the binary information for
# a properly formed pdf doc.
pdf_contents = get_pdf_contents()

file_to_be_saved = ContentFile(pdf_contents)

item = Item.objects.get(pk=1)

item.myfilefield.save('blarg.pdf', file_to_be_saved)
```

The get_pdf_contents function shouldn't be too hard to write - basically take whatever function you have already and chop it off before it funnels the results into an HttpResponse object. If you need help with that, post the code you have already.

Comment: @Evan Brumley, what did your `get_pdf_contents()` return? I am trying to do same but can't make file out of `pisa.CreatePDF()`